# Unable to Override in Volley Library

Tags: java, android-volley

Am currently developing a Android App for my Website. It happends that I have to use Volley Library to Parse my Json Data but am stuck on the way here is the Error part of my code

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {     
                            @Override               public void onResponse(String response) {}
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
                        })
```

And I always get these error:

```
Method onResponse and onErrorResponse doesnt override from super class and Theres no applicable constructor to '(int, java.lang.String, com.app.fxq.LoginActivity(annonymus),  com.app.fxq.LoginActivity(annonymus))'
```

Help me out how can i correct this error. Thanks

Comment: check the imports are correct or not?   `import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;`

Comment: All imports are correct.